# How to check if a word or group of words exist in given list of strings and how to extract that word?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings as follows :

```
list_of_words = ['all saints church','churchill college', "great saint mary's church", 'holy trinity church', "little saint mary's church", 'emmanuel college']
```

And I have a list of dictionaries that contains 'text' as key and a sentence as a value. It is as follows :

```
    "dict_sentences": [
    {
        "text": "Can you help me book a taxi going from emmanuel college to churchill college?"
    },
    {
        "text": "Yes, I could! What time would you like to depart from Emmanuel College?"
    },
    {
        "text": "I want a taxi to holy trinity church"
    },
    {
        "text": "Alright! I have a yellow Lexus booked to pick you up. The Contact number is 07543493643. Anything else I can help with?"
    },
    {
        "text": "No, that is everything I needed. Thank you!"
    },
    {
        "text": "Thank you! Have a great day!"
    }
]
```

For each sentence in dict_sentences, I want to check if any of the words from list_of_words exists in that sentence and if yes, I want to store it in another dictionary(as I have to further work on it).

For example, in the first sentence in dict_sentences, "*Can you help me book a taxi going from emmanuel college to churchill college?*", the substring "*churchill college*" and '*emmanuel college*' exists in our list_of_words, so I want to store the word '*churchill college*' and '*emmanuel college*' in another dictionary like `{ sent1 : ['churchill college', 'emmanuel college'] }`

So the expected output would be :

```
{  sent1 : ['churchill college', 'emmanuel college'] ,
   sent2 : [ 'emmanuel college' ],
   sent3 : [ 'holy trinity church' ]
} # ignore the rest of sentences as no word from list_of_words exist in them
```

The main problem here is checking if given sentence consists of word/group of words (like 'holy trinity church' - 3 words) in the given sentence and if yes, extracting the same. I went through other answers and following code was suggested for checking if a word from a list occurs in a sentence :

```
if any(word in sentence for word in list_of_words()): 
     pass
```

However, this way we can only check if the word from sentence exists in list_of_words(), to extract the word, I will have to run for loops. But, I refrain from using for loops as I need a very time efficient solution because I have around 300 documents where every document consist of such 10-15(or more) sentences and the list_of_words too is large i.e. around 300 strings. So, I need a time efficient way to check and extract the word from a given sentence that exists in list_of_words.

Comment: Based on what you need, don't think you have a choice but to loop through the whole list. What you can try is to shrink your documents first by checking if any appears first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` so there's no nested loop.

```
output = {}
find_words = re.compile('|'.join(list_of_words)).findall
for i, (s,) in enumerate(map(dict.values, data['dict_sentences']), 1):
    words = find_words(s.lower())
    if words:
        output[f"sent{i}"] = words
```

---

```
{'sent1': ['emmanuel college', 'churchill college'],
 'sent2': ['emmanuel college'],
 'sent3': ['holy trinity church']}
```

This can be done in a dict_comprehension as well using the walrus operator in python 3.8+ although may be a little overboard:

```
find_sent = re.compile('|'.join(list_of_words)).findall
iter_sent = enumerate(map(dict.values, data['dict_sentences']), 1)
output = {f"sent{i}": words for i, (s,) in iter_sent if (words := find_sent(s.lower()))}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way to do this with something like `itertools`, but I am not very familiar with it.

```py
test = {"dict_sentences":...} # I'm assuming it's a section of a json or a larger dictionary.

output = {}
j = 1
for sent in test["dict_sentences"]:
    addition = []
    for i in list_of_words:
        if i.upper() in sent["text"].upper():
            addition.append(i)
    if addition:
        output[f"sent{j}"] = addition
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a nested dict comprehension and compare the content by transforming both to lower case, for example:

```
output = {
    f"sent{i+1}": [
        phrase for phrase in list_of_words if phrase.lower() in sentence['text'].lower()
    ] for i,sentence in enumerate(dict_sentences)
}

output_without_empty_matches = { k:v for k,v in output.items() if v }

print(output_without_empty_matches)
>>> {'sent1': ['churchill college', 'emmanuel college'], 'sent2': ['emmanuel college'], 'sent3': ['holy trinity church']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[]
new_dict={}

for index, subdict in enumerate(dict_sentences):
    for word in list_of_words:
        if word in subdict['text'].lower():
            key="sent"+str(index+1)
            new_list.append(word)
            new_dict[key]=new_list
    new_list=[]

print(new_dict)
```